# What kind of question-vandalism by the OP is accptable?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/21933/4501) was changed (by edit by the OP) from a reasonable and answerable (indeed, answered) question, to a non-question (it now simply says "Please delete me"). My first question is, when a person asks a question, which receives an upvoted anwer, can the OP delete the question? This is a "how does SE work?" question.

The titular question is, should it be allowed that the original question is vandalized to the point that the visible question has no connection to the originally-asked question, and so that the answer has no relation to what presently stands as "the question"? (In the specific instance, I assume the solution is to roll back the edit and delete the individual's account: but still my question about policy stands).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[General policy for self-vandalism on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209438/211026). Essentially, vandalism is still vandalism, rollback is the appropriate action for a single occurrence. If multiple posts are vandalized, flagging for moderator attention is better.

In this case I rolled back the edit as the user only had one post on Law.SE. I briefly checked other network posts from that user, and a few others vandalized (and mostly already dealt with on the other sites too). I don't know how effective flagging might be for cross-network multiple vandalism as our moderators probably aren't moderators on the other sites.

As for deleting own question, this is how SE works ([quoted from here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/211026)):

> You can't delete *your own question* when it:
>
> - has an [answer with upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471) (even if it has a net negative score)
> - has an accepted answer
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes)
> - [has an answer with an awarded bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306966/changes-to-bounty-rules-removal-of-double-rep-retention-blocking-of-owner-dele?cb=1)

Comment: If you notice cross site vandalism, you can mention it in a custom flag and moderators can discuss it with moderators from other sites.

Comment: @jimsug Presumably either moderators from each of the vandalized sites will have to act against the vandalism on their own sites; *or* a Stack Exchange employee will have to get involved.

Comment: @MartinBonner Correct. Either or both are possible actions.